# log4j: archived files removing policy

Tags: java, log4j

I'm using TimeBasedRollingPolicy and RollingFileAppender to have a my logs rolling over and be archived as myLogFileName..log.gz:

```
    <appender class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender" name="myLogFile">
    <param value="/var/log/my/myLogFileName.log" name="File"/>
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="/var/log/my/myLogFileName.%d.log.gz" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param value="%d [%t] %-5p - %m%n" name="ConversionPattern"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

What I don't understand - is where it is defined when and how really old archived files will be totally removed from the filesystem?

And, if I want to keep always only no older than one month old files - where I can set it up (using log4j (extras))?

Answer (score 1):

`TimeBasedRollingPolicy` is defined by [`apache-log4j-extras`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/).  This dependency will need to be on the classpath in order to use that policy.

`RollingFileAppender` includes a `maxBackupIndex` property, which specifies the maximum number of rolled over backup files to retain.  However, I don't believe this property is supported when using a `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`.  This means that, when using `RollingFileAppender` with the `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`, old backup files will not be removed by the appender.

If you were using Logback as the logging implementation (perhaps in conjunction wiht SLF4J), then you could achieve the desired outcome using the
Logback [`RollingPolicy`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#onRollingPolicies).  I acknowledge that the question is seeking a log4j solution, but I'm not aware one.